Should I normalise a sample drawn from a skewed population?
I am interested in the effect of the number of inhabitants of political entities on certain political behaviours within these entities. It happens that the number of inhabitants is not evenly distributed across entities and my population is skewed (see plot below, skewness = 4.495).

Since I cannot collect data for all entities, I want to draw a sample of these entities. However, I wonder if I should draw a sample of these entities that is normalised regarding the number of inhabitants or not. Any thoughts?

Welcome to CV. What do you mean by normalized? Do you want to sample evenly across a range of the numbers of inhabitants?

Exactly. What I imagine an argument in favour: an even representation of the entire range of observation of number of inhabitants. What I imagine an argument against: a misrepresentation of the population. Hence my hesitation.

If you are interested in the effect of the number of inhabitants, then it makes sense to try and sample a wide range of possible counts.
This type of random sampling evenly along some other variable is called stratified sampling. In your case, there are no 'groups' to choose from, but you could for example, use binning to create different inhabitant number ranges. There are implementations for this readily available in most statistical software.
This would only be a disadvantage if you are not actually interested in the entire range of the number of inhabitants, but wanted to say something specifically about the "typical" city size, for example. However, this does not appear to be the case from your description.

That was what I had in mind. Thank you for confirming!

I do not yet have the necessary reputation for that. Besides, you talk about 'readily available' implementations. Could you think of one in R?

Ah, may bad. Searching online for "r stratified sampling" returns relevant results. This was one of the top results for me, which seems to be what you're looking for: Stratified random sampling from data frame
